# Can't seem to change value of text input with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to change the value of a text input with jQuery when a certain function passes. I used this code:

```
$('#find').attr("value", "newvalue");
```

But it's not changing it. This is the markup of the input I want to change:

```
<input type="text" id="find" class="input" />
```

I know it's getting to this peice of code because the jQuery either side of it executes and works.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I put your code here: http://jsbin.com/omoda3  (view the source). It works fine. You're doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("#find").val("newvalue");
```

Not sure why yours doesn't work though.
You might also need a name attribute on the input?  Not sure if that matters...

It could also be running before the input is created.  In which case wrap it in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //anything you want to do once the elements are all there.
});
```

Or just stick the script block after the element in your source (this might be a controversial suggestion).

Comment: Make sure the code runs after the element is created.  When does this code run?

Comment: The code runs when you click a button below the feild I want to change, so I know the element has been created. Everything is between `$(document).ready` anyway.

Comment: Nothing in the code looks wrong to me, so unless I'm overlooking something the problem is elsewhere on the page.  

Do you have a link or anything so I can see the whole page?

does something else on the page have the same id?

Comment: Seeing the context that the js is called in could help too.

Comment: make sure you dont have duplicate ids

Answer (score 4):

You would need to change the element's prop value.

```
$('#find').prop("value", "newvalue");
```

**attr**: holds the value the element had during page load

**prop**: holds the value of the element dynamically...the current state

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Yes...I do realize this is a very old post. However, I havent seen an answer provided as of yet. Thought this might keep someone from plucking their hair out  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use $('#find').val('newvalue');

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine, are you sure your selector is doing the right thing?

As a simple test try this:

```
$("#find").css({'background-color' : 'yellow'});
```

If the selector is right then the background item will go yellow.

Also, are you sure the code is being hit, there might be an error before hitting code, try sticking a breakpoint on the line of code and make sure it gets hit.